# Function sequence error, SQL state S1010 while executing a prepared Statement

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, odbc

I'm porting an old Access.mdb to a new MSSQL-Database with minor changes.
I have a simple loop:

```
//$_new is an MSSQL2011-ODBC-Datasource
//$_old is an old MSACCESS.mdb-ODBC-Datasource
$devices_result = odbc_exec($_old,"SELECT * FROM Druckerarchiv");
$device_insert_prepare = odbc_prepare($_new,"INSERT INTO Geraetearchiv (Kd_Nr,
[Typ],Seriennummer,Firma,Rg_Datum,Dauer,Markerart,Zus_Papierfach,Duplexeinheit,
Universalzufuhr,Plz,Ort,Strasse,Bemerkungen,Telefon,Fax,Ansprechpartner,Abteilung,
Wartung_BEGINN,Wartung_ENDE,Reaktions_TIME,Fix_TIME,Autom_Verl,Vertrags_Nr,
W_EK,W_VK,Wartung_LAUFZEIT,Absprachen,Drucker_USB,Drucker_LAN,Drucker_Parallel,
Drucker_Printserver,Drucker_Printserver_Typ,Drucker_Printserver_Sn,
Drucker_Zusatz,Email,Dienstleister,Garantieverlaengerung,
GVServicedienstleister,Aktiv,Typnummer,Firma_Standort) VALUES
(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
while($device = odbc_fetch_array($devices_result))
{
    $device_insert = array(
    utf8_encode($device['KD_NR']),
    utf8_encode($device['Druckertyp']),
    utf8_encode($device['Seriennummer']),
    utf8_encode($device['Firma']),
    $device['Rg-Datum'], 
    (float)$device['Dauer'],
    (float)$device['Markerart'],
    (int)$device['2_Papierfach'],
    (int)$device['Duplexeinheit'],
    (int)$device['Universalzufuhr'],
    utf8_encode($device['Plz']),
    utf8_encode($device['Ort']),
    utf8_encode($device['Straße']),
    utf8_encode($device['Bemerkungen']),
    utf8_encode($device['Telefon']),
    utf8_encode($device['Fax']),
    utf8_encode($device['Ansprechpartner']),
    utf8_encode($device['Abteilung']),
    $device['Wartung_BEGINN'],
    $device['Wartung_ENDE'], 
    (int)$device['Reaktions_TIME'],
    (int)$device['Fix_TIME'],
    (int)$device['Autom_Verl'],
    utf8_encode($device['VERTRAGS_NR']),
    (double)$device['W-EK'],
    (double)$device['W-VK'],
    (float)$device['Wartung_LAUFZEIT'],
    utf8_encode($device['Absprachen']),
    0, 
    (int)$device['Ethernet'], 
    0, 
    0, 
    '', 
    '', 
    (($device['Y-Adapter/Typ'])?
    ("Hat Y-Adapter ".$device['Y-Adapter/Typ']." SN: ".$device['Y-Adapter/SN']):null),
    '', 
    (int)$servicedienstleister[$markerart[
    (int)$device['Markerart']]], //dienstleister
    '', 
    '', 
    1, 
    '',
    '',
    );
    odbc_execute($device_insert_prepare,$device_insert);
}
```

This loop runs for the first 2 to 3 times. But after that it failes every single run and throws

```
Warning: odbc_execute() [function.odbc-execute]: SQL error: 
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Function sequence error, 
SQL state S1010 in SQLDescribeParameter
```

Since this loop should do ~30k round's i want to run it as prepared statement and execute it ~30k times.
I already tried to turn off autocommit.
Did i miss something?

Comment: what do you mean by this `[39x?]`?

Comment: its just a shortcut for `?,?,?,?,?,...`. 39 questionmarks to match the 39 columns.

Comment: Please update your question with the actual code you have used, unless your source code exactly matches the above statement. Using shortcuts in the question is problematic.

Comment: @ThomasMueller the query itself run's fine, i removed the unnecessary part to keep the post small. But if it help's you, there you go.

Comment: @BenediktMokroß Simplifying is very good actually, but the problem was that it was an illegal statement and not obvious that you left out some text. I have no idea what the problem could be. Could you try to simplify the program, for example only insert those columns that are needed to reproduce the problem? Trying to find the problem is sometimes a kind of binary search. Or maybe you find the reason by looking at the difference in the data (which data worked, which didn't).

Comment: @ThomasMueller it's regardless how many Columns i try to insert. I tested 1, 3 and all 39. I even tried to insert the first Dataset (which worked) multiple times: same error.

Comment: @BenediktMokroß Ok, that's interesting, so it's not the data. I also suspect it's a "one active statement per connection" limit (as Nick has answered)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on ODBC tracing, that should give you a clue as to the problem.

The fact you are going to SQL Server makes me suspect you are hitting the one active statement limit of SQL Server. Maybe consider using MARS or any other of the other workarounds (or two connections).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Nick i got on the right path to fix my problem. I used a MARS-Connection.
I'm posting my own answer with the correct Connection-DSN so other developers with the same problem won't need to search it.

```
$_new = odbc_connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'.
                     'SERVER=<ServerIP>;'.
                     'DATABASE=<DatabaseName>;'.
                     'MARS_Connection=yes;',
                     '<user>',
                     '<password>');
```